# Do i need to declare none for mypy pytest functions?

Tags: pytest, mypy

So i basically just read in the documentation that

> If a function does not explicitly return a value, give it a return type of None. Using a None result in a statically typed context results in a type check error

Does that also include pytest functions? Do i have to annotate every pytest func with None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, or run mypy with [`--check-untyped-defs`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-check-untyped-defs), though of course that may hide other functions you've forgotten to annotate

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was just wondering why 
def mypyso():
    return "blab"

x: int = mypyso()

Isn't causing any error at all

Comment: @supersick I imagine that argument and return types are effectively `Any` unless marked otherwise

Comment: "that may hide other functions you've forgotten to annotate" No, this flag does not affect `--disallow-untyped-defs` flag, so you still have errors on all untyped functions. If you declare override (in `[[tool.mypy.overrides]]` pyproject.toml config) to `disallow_untyped_defs = false` only in tests module, you can ignore typing test functions and still have some type checking there.